# AngularJS - custom directive with attributes in templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I have some templates for format text, *frecuencia-dia.html* or *frecuencia-mes.html* for example.

I want call a dinamic template using the attributes *tipo* (text plain) and *clave* (variable scope).

```
<ng-formato-texto tipo="frecuencia" clave="{{prod.claveFrecuencia}}" />

app.directive('ngFormatoTexto', function() {
    return {
        templateUrl: function(elem, attr){
            return '/formats/'+attr.tipo+'-'+attr.clave+'.html';
        }
    };
});
```

But don't work, this try load *frecuencia-%7B%7Bprod.clavePrueba%7D%7D.html*

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you put the plunkr? https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use the dynamic template in directive.

As documentation say:

> Note: You do not currently have the ability to access scope variables from the templateUrl function, since the template is requested before the scope is initialized.

To create a dynamic directive can use `ng-include`.

Example:

```
app.directive('ngFormatoTexto', function() {
 return {
     template: '<div ng-include="path"></div>',
     scope:{
       tipo:"@",
       clave:"="
     },
     link:function(scope){
       scope.path= '/formats/'+scope.tipo+'-'+scope.clave+'.html'
     }
 };
});
```